# Weird case with MemoryLayout using a struct protocol, different size reported

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I'm working on a drawing engine using Metal. I am reworking from a previous version, so starting from scratch

I was getting error **Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)**

After some debugging I placed the blame to my drawPrimitives routine, I found the case quite interesting

I will have a variety of brushes, all of them will work with specific Vertex info

So I said, why not? Have all the brushes respond to a protocol

The protocol for the Vertices will be this:

```
protocol MetalVertice {}
```

And the Vertex info used by this specific brush will be:

```
struct PointVertex:MetalVertice{
    var pointId:UInt32
    let relativePosition:UInt32
}
```

The brush can be called either by giving Vertices previously created or by calling a function to create those vertices. Anyway, the real drawing happens at the vertice function

```
var vertices:[PointVertex] = [PointVertex].init(repeating: PointVertex(pointId: 0,
                                                                               relativePosition: 0),
                                                        count: totalVertices)

        for (verticeIdx, pointIndex) in pointsIndices.enumerated(){
            vertices[verticeIdx].pointId = UInt32(pointIndex)
        }

 for vertice in vertices{
            print("size: \(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertice))")
        }

        self.renderVertices(vertices: vertices,
                            forStroke: stroke,
                            inDrawing: drawing,
                            commandEncoder: commandEncoder)

        return vertices
    }


    func renderVertices(vertices: [MetalVertice], forStroke stroke: LFStroke, inDrawing drawing:LFDrawing, commandEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder) {

        if vertices.count > 1{
        print("vertices a escribir: \(vertices.count)")
            print("stride: \(MemoryLayout<PointVertex>.stride)")
            print("size of array \(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertices))")
            for vertice in vertices{
                print("ispointvertex: \(vertice is PointVertex)")
                print("size: \(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertice))")
            }
        }
        let vertexBuffer = LFDrawing.device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices,
                                                       length: MemoryLayout<PointVertex>.stride * vertices.count,
                                                       options: [])
```

This was the issue, calling this specific code produces these results in the console:

```
size: 8
size: 8
vertices a escribir: 2
stride: 8
size of array 8
ispointvertex: true
size: 40
ispointvertex: true
size: 40
```

In the previous function, the size of the vertices is 8 bytes, but for some reason, when they enter the next function they turn into 40 bytes, so the buffer is incorrectly  constructed

if I change the function signature to:

```
    func renderVertices(vertices: [PointVertex], forStroke stroke: LFStroke, inDrawing drawing:LFDrawing, commandEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder) {
```

The vertices are correctly reported as 8 bytes long and the draw routine works as intended

Anything I'm missing? if the MetalVertice protocol introducing some noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fulfill the requirement that value types conforming to protocols be able to perform dynamic dispatch (and also in part to ensure that containers of protocol types are able to assume that all of their elements are of uniform size), Swift uses what are called *existential containers* to hold the data of protocol-conforming value types alongside metadata that points to the concrete implementations of each protocol. If you've heard the term *protocol witness table*, that's what's getting in your way here.

The particulars of this are beyond the scope of this answer, but you can check out [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/?time=1547) and [this post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-01-exploring-swift-memory-layout-part-ii.html) for more info.

The moral of the story is: don't assume that Swift will lay out out your structs as-written. Swift can reorder struct members and add padding or arbitrary metadata, and it gives you practically no control over this. Instead, declare the structs you need to use in your Metal code in a C or Objective-C file and import them via a bridging header. If you want to use protocols to make it easier to address your structs polymorphically, you need to be prepared to copy them member-wise into your regular old C structs and prepared to pay the memory cost that that convenience entails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Always great to know how things work in the background, will try to avoid it from now on. Also, thanks for metalByExample! Couldn't be building this thing without it